# Overriding external gitlab.yml file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Suppose we have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that reads in a `common.gitlab-ci.complete.yml` file:

```
include: common.gitlab-ci.complete.yml
```

Suppose that `common.gitlab-ci.complete.yml` has the following stages:

```
stages:
  - build
  - unit-test
  - mutation-test
```

In the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, how do we ignore the `unit-test` and `mutation-test` stages? Would it be something like:

```
include: common.gitlab-ci.complete.yml
stages:
  - build
  #- unit-test
  #- mutation-test
```

Would these `stages` override the one in the `common.gitlab-ci.complete.yml` file?

Answer (score 3):

(I have not yet checked this code for accuracy. Treat it as pseudocode.)

You're asking to remove all jobs in a stage. If you look at the [documentation for the `include:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include) keyword, you'll note that the YAML is always merged with your current CI script. So no, you can't just add a statement like "Disable all jobs in stage A".

Here's an idea... recall that

> If a stage is defined but no jobs use it, the stage is not visible in the pipeline...
>
> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages

So what you could do is add a mechanism for disabling all jobs in that stage. Then the stage will disappear as well. That mechanism might be checking a variable in [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules).

So if you wrote the `common.gitlab-ci.complete.yml` with templates that check a variable to disable the job...

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - unit-test
  - package

.unit-test-stage:
  stage: unit-test
  when: on_success
  rules:
    - if: $DISABLE_UNIT_TESTS
      when: never

unit-test-job-a:
  extends: .unit-test-stage
  script:
    - echo "do stuff"

unit-test-job-b:
  extends: .unit-test-stage
  script:
    - echo "do more stuff"
```

Then maybe your top-level `.gitlab-ci.yml` would simply set that known variable in its *global* `variables` section like this:

```yaml
include: common.gitlab-ci.complete.yml

variables:
  DISABLE_UNIT_TESTS: 1
```